# How to add UI elements programatically to existing nib files

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I wonder how to add UI elements programatically to existing nib files.

If I create a view programatically in `loadView` method and I add code like the following, the label displays correctly.

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,2,150,100)];

[self.view addView:lbl];
```

But how to add the label to an existing nib file?

Comment: You need to use `viewDidLoad` which is called after the view has finished loading (from the `nib`). You only use the `loadView` method if you are setting up your view completely in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul.s pointed out, you need to perform your custom code in `viewDidLoad` method.

From Apple documentation.

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its
>   associated views into memory. This method is called regardless of
>   whether the views were stored in a nib file or created
>   programmatically in the loadView method. This method is most commonly
>   used to perform additional initialization steps on views that are
>   loaded from nib files.

So, in your controller you could do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // your other views here

   // call addSubview method on self.view
}
```

Why do you do this? Because here you are sure that view has loaded in memory and outlets has been set correctly.

On the contrary, about `loadView` method

> If you override this method in order to create your views manually,
>   you should do so and assign the root view of your hierarchy to the
>   view property. (The views you create should be unique instances and
>   should not be shared with any other view controller object.) Your
>   custom implementation of this method should not call super.

An example could be:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.view = contentView; 

    // call addSubview method on self.view
}
```

I suggest you to read [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW1).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `viewDidLoad`

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,2,150,100)];
[self.view addSubView:lbl];
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, to modify nib file programmatically is not possible.

You can add view into viewDidLoad of UIViewController method.